# What feats specifically benefit a character's shield use?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, shield

I was building a defensively-minded cohort today when I realized that I've searched stacks of books for all the shield-boosting feats several times in the past, and decided that the Pathfinder community could benefit from a community-maintained list of shield feats.

What feats specifically benefit a character that uses a shield?

Notes for answers:

- I am *not* interested in feats like Dodge that boost defense in general, without the use of a shield.
- I am *not* interested in feats that help you overcome an opponent's shield.
- I am *not* interested in feats like Arcane Shield that give you a shield bonus from a source other than a physical buckler, light or heavy shield, or tower shield.
- I *am* interested in feats that improve shield-bashing.
- I *am* interested in feats that improve shields in ways besides +AC.

Comment: Related [meta discussion](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5773/i-want-to-post-some-questions-that-will-require-finite-community-wiki-list-an).

Comment: The given requirements and limitations make this a sufficiently narrow and answerable question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Organized by book, then by non-bashing to bashing, then in an arbitrary order.  A short description of the feats' benefits are appreciated but not required, links likewise.)

From the Core Rulebook:

- Shield Proficiency is obvious in the case of characters who aren't already trained in shield-use.
- Shield Focus gives a flat bonus to shield AC.
- [Greater Shield Focus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/greater-shield-focus-combat---final) gives another flat bonus to shield AC.
- Improved Shield Bash permits the use of shield AC even after performing a shield bash.
- Shield Slam permits a free bull rush maneuver after a successful shield bash.
- Shield Master reduces two-weapon fighting penalties when using a shield as a weapon.

From the Advanced Player's Guide:

- [Covering Defense](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/covering-defense-combat) gives adjacent allies a cover bonus to AC when you use the Total Defense action.
- [Missile Shield](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/missile-shield-combat) permits a shield-user to occasionally negate a ranged attack against them.
- [Ray Shield](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/ray-shield-combat) lets a shield user deflect a ranged touch attack, although the shield can take damage.
- [Saving Shield](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/saving-shield-combat) permits a shield-user to grant an ally a bonus to AC.
- [Shield Wall](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/shield-wall-combat-teamwork) is a teamwork feat that allows allies with shields to boost each other's AC.
- [Duck and Cover](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/duck-and-cover-teamwork) is a teamwork feat that gives a cover AC bonus against ranged attacks if your teammate has a shield, plus some reflex save options.
- [Shielded Caster](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/shielded-caster-teamwork) is a teamwork feat that gives you a bonus to concentration checks, increasing if your ally has a shield.
- [Shield Specialization](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/shield-specialization-combat) gives you better AC against critical hit confirmation rolls, and applies your shield bonus to your CMD with your chosen shield.
- [Greater Shield Specialization](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/greater-shield-specialization-combat) gives you even more AC against critical hit confirmation rolls, and lets you negate 1 crit per day.
- [Mounted Shield](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/mounted-shield-combat) adds your shield bonus to your mounts AC.
- [Bashing Finish](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/bashing-finish-combat) gives a free shield bash after getting a crit with a weapon.

From Ultimate Combat:

- [Fortified Armor Training](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/fortified-armor-training-combat) isn't totally shield focused, but lets you break armor or shield instead of taking a critical hit

From Ultimate Magic:

- [Channeled Shield Wall](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/channeled-shield-wall) takes a use of Channel Energy to give a deflection bonus to AC to you and adjacent allied while using a shield.

Comment: Nearly any feat that can be used to apply a bonus to a weapon, can be applied to a shield being used to bash(weapon focus/specialization, ect.)